# Weird R nested for loop behavior

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I have the following code:

```
for(i in(1:5) )
{
    for(j in ( (i+1) :5) )
{
    cat (i,", ",j,"\n")

}
}
```

My expectation is, it will list all pair of numbers from 1 to 5. However, I am getting the following when I run the above R script.

```
1 ,  2 
1 ,  3 
1 ,  4 
1 ,  5 
2 ,  3 
2 ,  4 
2 ,  5 
3 ,  4 
3 ,  5 
4 ,  5 
5 ,  6 
5 ,  5
```

The last two rows are totally puzzling me. Had this been a case of border inclusion/exclusion, 6 would always be printed after 1,2,3,4, but it's only happening after 5. Also, the last pair of 5,5 makes no sense either.

Comment: If I am understanding what you're asking - you want 1,1; 1,2; 1,3... 5,5; then should your inner loop be `for(j in ( (i) :5) )`?

Comment: I actually don't want 1:1, but 1:2. That is, no same value pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does exactly what you asked it to do:

```
6:5
#[1] 6 5
```

See

```
?`:`
```

for more info.

Comment: I see, how would i go about implementing what I actually intended?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz loop `i` from 1 to 4

Comment: I think I got it, I change the outer limit to 4. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz if you just want the numbers - do `combn(c(1:5), 2)`

Answer (score 3):

I thihk your loop should be,

```
for(i in(1:5) )
{
  for(j in ( (i) :5) )
  {
    cat (i,", ",j,"\n")

  }
}

1 ,  1 
1 ,  2 
1 ,  3 
1 ,  4 
1 ,  5 
2 ,  2 
2 ,  3 
2 ,  4 
2 ,  5 
3 ,  3 
3 ,  4 
3 ,  5 
4 ,  4 
4 ,  5 
5 ,  5
```

**Update**

In order to get results similar to those of `combn` just an `if(·)` condition as in:

```
for(i in(1:5) )
{
  for(j in ( (i) :5) )
  {
    if(i!=j){
      cat (i,", ",j,"\n")
    }

  }
}
```

This way you avoid printing values when `i` is equal to `j` (I think this is what you called "repeated value pair").

Comment: Not exactly what I want, I don't want repeated value pair.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz I think I got what you meant, see the update. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can get that using this:

```
t(combn(5, 2))
```

Result:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    5
 [8,]    3    4
 [9,]    3    5
[10,]    4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write if state.
Something like

```
for(i in(1:5) )
{
    if (i < 4) {
        for(j in ( (i+1) :5) )
        {
            cat (i,", ",j,"\n")
        }
    }
}
```